# Spark structured streaming drop duplicates keep last

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I would like to maintain a streaming dataframe that get "update".

To do so I will use `dropDuplicates`.

But `dropDuplicates` drop the latest change.

How can I retain the last only?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to select the last record on id column by removing other duplicates, you can use the window functions and filter on row_number = count. Check this out

```
scala> val df = Seq((120,34.56,"2018-10-11"),(120,65.73,"2018-10-14"),(120,39.96,"2018-10-20"),(122,11.56,"2018-11-20"),(122,24.56,"2018-10-20")).toDF("id","amt","dt")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, amt: double ... 1 more field]

scala> val df2=df.withColumn("dt",'dt.cast("date"))
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, amt: double ... 1 more field]

scala> df2.show(false)
+---+-----+----------+
|id |amt  |dt        |
+---+-----+----------+
|120|34.56|2018-10-11|
|120|65.73|2018-10-14|
|120|39.96|2018-10-20|
|122|11.56|2018-11-20|
|122|24.56|2018-10-20|
+---+-----+----------+


scala> df2.createOrReplaceTempView("ido")

scala> spark.sql(""" select id,amt,dt,row_number() over(partition by id order by dt) rw, count(*) over(partition by id) cw from ido """).show(false)
+---+-----+----------+---+---+
|id |amt  |dt        |rw |cw |
+---+-----+----------+---+---+
|122|24.56|2018-10-20|1  |2  |
|122|11.56|2018-11-20|2  |2  |
|120|34.56|2018-10-11|1  |3  |
|120|65.73|2018-10-14|2  |3  |
|120|39.96|2018-10-20|3  |3  |
+---+-----+----------+---+---+


scala> spark.sql(""" select id,amt,dt from (select id,amt,dt,row_number() over(partition by id order by dt) rw, count(*) over(partition by id) cw from ido) where rw=cw """).show(false)
+---+-----+----------+
|id |amt  |dt        |
+---+-----+----------+
|122|11.56|2018-11-20|
|120|39.96|2018-10-20|
+---+-----+----------+


scala>
```

If you want to sort on dt descending you can just give "order by dt desc" in the over(0 clause.. Does this help?

Comment: This is the case for spark in batch.
My use case is streaming and I want to get a DF that represents the unique set of events + updates from the stream.
This is supported with dropDuplicates the only issue is which event is dropped, currently the new event is dropped.
I need to replace the current with the new event from the stream

Comment: I have not used streaming, but the streaming should be similar and so I posted.

Comment: There are some differences. In my case I want to take advantage of the fact that the streaming DF is mutable

Comment: Have you found out the solution? @idofriedman